# Jquery 1.4.2 Form submit event handler is firing after form submit in IE 7/8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am facing issue in form submit event handler. here is my code
I am using Jquery 1.4.2

```
<FORM id="mysearchform" method="get" action="http://www.abc.com/results.aspx?q=" target=_blank sizcache="1694" sizset="0" jQuery1347023310528="3">

<DIV class="search">
<span><span>
<LABEL class=hide for=q>Search:</LABEL>
<INPUT accessKey=S id="a" class="abc" name="a" maxLength="50" value="Images" size=69 type="search" autocomplete="off" selectionStart="0" jQuery1347023310528="108">
<INPUT style="WIDTH: 185px; HEIGHT: 33px" class="img" title="Search" alt="Search" value="Search" src="http://dummyimage.com/180x35" type=image>
<INPUT name="form" value="abcd" type="hidden"></SPAN></SPAN></DIV>
</FORM>
```

I have one event handler for mysearchform which is used to change value of form input element and value of text box with id "a" so that on form submit I can change value of text box i.e. (add additional value)

```
$("#mysearchform").submit(mysubmitHandler);
```

in mysubmitHandler, I am changing values for "a" and form input element. This code is working fine in IE9, FF 4.0 and latest version of chrome. However in IE 7 and IE8, before coming to "mysubmitHandler", new window is opening (I am showing search result in new window). So my changes in  are not getting appended to query string on search window.

in other browsers, "mysubmitHandler" is firing first and then new window is opening.

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code?

Comment: var searchForm=$("#mysearchform");
searchForm.submit(onSubmit);


function onSubmit()
{
  var $formElement=$("input[name=form]",$(this));
  $formElement.attr("value",($("#a").val() +"search"));
}

however this code doesn't matter as it is called after form submit. By saying that, it means new page is opened in tab and then my handler is getting called, which is not reflecting my changes.

Comment: jQuery 1.4.2, retro style....

Comment: I am not getting about retro style. If your question is which version then I am using 1.4.2 min js

Comment: I was just commenting on the version of jquery you are using, it's quite old or "retro"

Comment: yes. I have to live with that only as of now. Is it known issue in 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did reproduce the problem. Here is on my setup what fixed the issue :

(Commented in the code what I changed)

```
// Wrapped everything in jquery onready event function $(function() { }) 
$(function() {
    var $searchForm = $("#mysearchform");

    function onSubmit() {
        var $formElement = $("input[name=form]", $(this));
        $formElement.attr("value", ($("#a").val() + "search"));
    }

    // Put the handler *after* the function definition
    $searchForm.submit(onSubmit);
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work for me. I have 4 more event handlers attached to that form doing different work. all handler's are firing but after opening new tab. I can not put all handlers above declaration. Is there any specific reason its not working in IE 8 and 7 only. Working perfectly fine in IE 9 and other latest browsers

Comment: Why cant you declare the handler functions beforehand ? To test your code, I used this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3VvEk/ , which does not works in IE7, like your description, nor does it validate if you click on `JSLint`, because onSubmit is not defined. Just putting the event handling code after the declaration makes the jsfiddle validates, *and*, it works in IE7